# Substack a character

Tags: equations

I have tried to substack under a regular character different from `\sum` or `\prod` and the result is not desired. Here is what I am obtaining:

[image]

I want to have the 'i = 1' underneath the U.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
   U^n{\substack{i=1}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a sketch of what you'd like to obtain and, perhaps, some source for such notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply write the image that you provided as the structure of a sum. See MWE image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\mathop{U}\limits_{i=1}^{n}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

TeX distinguishes several math classes: Ord for ordinary objects (like U), Op for operators (like \sum) and several others. You can re-type the default class by `\matop{U}` (gives U in Op class, i.e allows to use indexes above and below). But there is another feature of the `\mathop` TeX primitive. If there is only single object, it is centered to math axis. If you don't want this feature then use `\mathop{{}U}`. The empty object is object too, there is more than single object and centering to math axis is deactivated.

The sub/super-scripts of Op objects are above and below only in display style. If you want to have them above and below in text style too, then use `\limits` TeX primitive just before the subscript constructor `_`. The whole matter looks like this:

```
$\mathop{{}U^n}\limits_{n=1}$
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution, using a correct syntax:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
       \substack{U^n \\ \scriptstyle i=1}
    \end{equation*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]